# What does the following segment do - Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with the following function. I can't understand what it does, because I'm new to Python, can you help me, please. Thanks in advance.

```
def foo(limit):
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False
    for (i,b) in enumerate(a):
        if b:
        yield i
        for n in xrange(i*i,limit,i):
            a[n] = False
```

Comment: It will throw a syntax error because you have wrong indentation on `yield i`. Apart from that - which part exactly do you not understand? (Asking for an explanation of the entire code is a bit much)

Comment: i think it is prime numbers generator which use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: @furas It does resemble the Sieve of eratosthenes but it looks like it is slightly different here : see the last for-loop it only crosses numbers starting from i² (vs i in the regular sieve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example of Binary Indexed Tree.